# Java returning a variable

Tags: java

I am trying to use a method below to return a variable "charges"

```
public static double billingM(double income, int min, double rate) {
    double charges;
    if (income <= 25000 && min <= 30)
        charges = 0;
    if (income <= 25000 && min > 30)
        charges = rate * 0.4;
    if (income > 25000 && min <= 20)
        charges = 0;
    if (income > 25000 && min > 20)
        charges = rate * 0.7;
    return charges;
} //End of Billing Method
```

How do I get it to return the variable charges??? It won't how I have it right now.

Comment: it already returns it, what is the problem?

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't return charges? It is returning charges at the moment..

Comment: It isn't though. It should, but it isn't.

Comment: *It won't how I have it right now.* That is not the correct way to describe the issue. Whenever you have some compiler error please make sure you indicate that and put up the error message.

Answer (score 2):

`double charges;` is a local variable. You need to initialize it since your if statements do not cover all possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your local variables, so try to do:

```
double charges = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

When i try to execute this program, i observed few things

1)Local variable `charges` is not at all `initialized` before usinng.

so all local variables must be `initialized` before you use them.

or else you will get compile time error like "`local variable may not have been initialized`"

2)if you want to return variable along with the value , you `cant return multiple values` directly so use `map` with key as variable name and value as map value.